# localScroll in all direction

Tags: jquery

So I am working on a small experimental web project and I have run into some jQuery issues (since I am pretty new to, and bad at jQuery):
Why I want to achive is to get all a.arrow to scroll to it's url-div (by ID).
Here is an example of the (mind u, background pics are missing, so it looks a bit sad, but that hardly matters):
http://jsfiddle.net/popmouth/P8Fvq/1/
I am happy for help, and I would love to learn jQuery better!
Cheers
Carl

Comment: This is kind of what I am after:
http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/localScroll/